# pass array to Array#each, internally, it uses reference or value

Tags: ruby, pass-by-reference

```
array1 = [0, 1]

# CASE 1:  
[array1].each do |arr| 
  arr = [3, 4] 
end

=> [0, 1]

# CASE 2:
[array1].each do |arr| 
  arr.delete_if { |ele| ele == 0 }
end

=> [[1]]
```

I thought ruby always passes array by reference. Why didn't it change the value of array in CASE 1 but did change it in CASE 2?  thanks.

Comment: I think the output of your first block is really [[0, 1]].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first situation, all you've done is change which object `arr` points at - you haven't actually modified the original. This can be proven with the following script:

```
# Given our test value...
test_array = [1, 2]

# we can verify the values and the object_ids
puts "Value of `test_array`: #{test_array.inspect}"
puts "Object_id of `test_array`: #{test_array.object_id}"

# now, let's put it in a container and run it through a block
@array_container = [test_array]

@array_container.each do |arr|

  # Just to prove that `arr` points at test_array
  puts "Object_id of `arr`: #{arr.object_id}"

  # and that it's the same as the first element in our container
  puts "@container.first.object_id: #{@array_container.first.object_id}"

  # but, when we re-assign our block variable
  arr = [3, 4]

  # we get different values
  puts "Object_id of `arr`: #{arr.object_id}"
  puts "@container.first.object_id: #{@array_container.first.object_id}"
end
```

Which outputs...

```
Value of `test_array`: [1, 2]
Object_id of `test_array` : 2150710260

Object_id of `arr`        : 2150710260
@container.first.object_id: 2150710260

Object_id of `arr`        : 2150708040
@container.first.object_id: 2150710260
```

So how is that different in Case 2? In case 2, you're actually calling a self-destructive method, which will make changes to the original object that is being referenced by `arr`

Comment: in Case 1, is there a way to assign the new data to original object?

Comment: You'd have to use something like `Array#map` which replaces each element with the result of the block.

Comment: tried [array1].map { |arr| arr = [56, 78] }, it still doesn't change the array1 value.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? `Array#map` will return a new array. Are you trying to change values in an array, or something else?

Comment: yes, i want to change the values in the array.  [arr1, arr2, arr3].each do |a| "some logics here" end

Comment: Then you want either `new_array = old_array.map { |x| processing_logic }` or `old_array.map! { |x| processing_logic }` to do it in place.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue has to do with scope. The `do-end` construct is really a new block, so when you declare `arr = [3, 4]` you are instantiating a new `arr = [3, 4]` within that block. Whereas in Case 2 you are modifying the reference directly. To do the same thing in Case 1 would be something like:

```
[array1].each do |arr| 
  arr.each_index do |i|
    arr[i]+=3
  end 
end

=> [[3,4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`.each` simply calls the block with each element of the collection it's called on (in this case `[array1]`) in turn. Passing an argument just assigns it to a parameter. Your example can be simplified to the following:

```
# CASE 1:  
array1 = [0, 1]
arr = array1
arr = [3, 4]
array1

=> [0, 1]

# CASE 2:
array1 = [0, 1]
arr = array1
arr.delete_if { |ele| ele == 0 }
array1

=> [1]
```